# App loses its ability to remember its stack when launched from another application

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, task

Now that I have researched this even more I am rewriting this to make it clearer.  If you are looking for more info, there is some available in older edits.

What is happening:

(This refers to an application that has not set any launchMode
settings and so is using the defaults)

1. You launch an app from the Market or from the Installer.  This
   launches the root/main activity of the application with the
   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag and no categories.  Right now the
   applications stack is [ A ]
2. Then you proceed to the next activity in the application. Now the
   stack in this task is [ A > B ]
3. Then you press the home key and then relaunch the same application
   by pressing it's icon from either the home screen or the app tray.
4. What is expected at this point is that activity B will show, since
   that is where you left off.  However A is shown and the tasks stack is
   [ A > B > A ]  This second instance of A is launched with the
   following flags:  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
   FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_IF_NEEDED, and FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT.  It
   also has the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER category.

At this point, if you hit the back key, it will return you to B, as it
was when you left it.

Looking at the documentation it seems as if
FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT should only be set for activities that
use the singleTask or singleTop launchModes.  However, this
application has not set any launchModes and is therefore using the
default standard launchMode.

I assume this is not suppose to happen in this case?

I should also note, that once it gets into this weird state, then it happens everytime the app is launched from the home screen or app tray. If the task is finished (restarting the
phone, force stopping the app, or hitting back all the way through the
stack) will fix this issue and will no longer launch it incorrectly.
It only happens if you launch the app from the installer or market and
then try to launch it from the launcher.

So in summary, why is this happening?  Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: You are very observant! The same thing started happening to my application and I really didn't know what to do with it! Especially since when I install the apk from within Eclipse it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity stack ordering problem when launching application from Android app installer and from Home screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356467/activity-stack-ordering-problem-when-launching-application-from-android-app-inst)

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 and broken still in 2019!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround I have come up with so far.  Some other workarounds I have seen involved looking at the currently running tasks.  However, I really did not want to have to ask for another permission (GET_TASKS) from the user just to make a work around.

Please let me know if you see any holes in this.

In the main/root activity's onCreate method, check if the intent has
the FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT set and if so, call finish().  This
then pops the extra instance of A off the stack [ A > B > A ] becomes
[ A > B ] and from the users perspective, it launches into the
activity they were expecting.

It seems to work in all of my tests so far.  My only worry is that if
there is some weird case where someones launcher would always flag a
launch with FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT even if the app wasn't
already in a task, and therefore would completely lock them out
because it would call finish() and not have anything in the stack to
return to.

--

As requested in the comments here is how you can check if an intent a specific flag:

```
int flags = intent.getFlags();
boolean hasFlag = flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT == Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT;
```

--

Also I should note that I am still seeing this problem occur sometimes with this fix in place.  It doesn't seem to be a perfect solution.

Comment: @GSree, yes because I am handling the config changes myself.  I'm not sure what would happen if I turn it off.  Though, I assume it would be fine.  The problem seems more related to how it is launched.

Comment: How can you test an Intent against certain flags? I.e. how do you know that the Intent was called with FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT?

Answer (score -1):

Overriding of onConfigurationChanged() should help you to retain the state.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> Configuration Changes
>
> If the configuration of the device (as defined by the Resources.Configuration class) changes, then anything displaying a user interface will need to update to match that configuration. Because Activity is the primary mechanism for interacting with the user, it includes special support for handling configuration changes.
>
> Unless you specify otherwise, a configuration change (such as a change in screen orientation, language, input devices, etc) will cause your current activity to be destroyed, going through the normal activity lifecycle process of onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() as appropriate. If the activity had been in the foreground or visible to the user, once onDestroy() is called in that instance then a new instance of the activity will be created, with whatever savedInstanceState the previous instance had generated from onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
>
> This is done because any application resource, including layout files, can change based on any configuration value. Thus the only safe way to handle a configuration change is to re-retrieve all resources, including layouts, drawables, and strings. Because activities must already know how to save their state and re-create themselves from that state, this is a convenient way to have an activity restart itself with a new configuration.
>
> In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your activity based on one or more types of configuration changes. This is done with the android:configChanges attribute in its manifest. For any types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will receive a call to your current activity's onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) method instead of being restarted. If a configuration change involves any that you do not handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) will not be called."

Comment: thanks for the response.  I am actually already overriding the configurationChanges for all of my activities but I don't think this really applies to the problem.  The previous activity is never even called again, the call goes straight to the root activity A.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty I had a similar issue, I used a singleton class object to store the last activity of the object

Comment: But then don't you lose the state of the activities since their onSavedInstanceState values would have been wiped out?

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty well... for me the activity had logical points where I could trigger updating singleton class. eg. end of play of a media file... implemented a MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener and updated my singleton. Not sure if your application has logical points where you could control.