# Strange issue in Android when I install app to my device

Tags: android, installation

I am facing a very strange issue in Android.

I have created an Android application,so when I install app to device from Eclipse it works fine, shows no issue.
But when I save the apk file in phone memory or SD card (or via email) and then install the apk file on device it shows an issue.

When I open the app it works fine but when I minimize it & start from applications the app again restarts from its first activity (not from where I left) but if I open app from recent apps it starts from where I left.

I am really not getting what is the problem.

Please help.

Comment: it seems due to lack of memory android framework killing your application  you can put some log in onLowMemory() and check whether its the case or not

Comment: @Akki but it works fine when I install app directly from Eclipse.

Comment: i thought you were installing in emulator from eclipse. Is it not the case?

Comment: No,installing from Eclipse to device directly.

Comment: try with uninstall app and than reinstall i think you are trying to ovrride installed apps that may cause problem

Answer (score 2):

It's because a different flag is set when starting from eclipse, and different one when starting from package installer.

try this:

```
1) copy APK to device
2) run APK and install application but don't choose "Open" when installation is over
3) close package installer
4) run your application from launcher
```

it should work exactly as from eclipse

Comment: Great it works.I followed what you said.But how to solve this issue & how would user come to know it has to start from launcher only after installation.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything here, because it's the system who is setting those flags..

i think it's the same issue as here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356467/activity-stack-ordering-problem-when-launching-application-from-android-app-inst

Answer (score 0):

You can check flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT in onCreate() of your first activity and then finishing if it is set.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
    // Here activity is brought to front, not created,
    // so finishing this will get you to the last viewed activity
    finish();
    return;
    }

// Regular code.
}
```